# Finding power of user input

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I'm currently working on an assignment, and while I have had no issues with the first two requirements, I'm now running into an issue with the last one. It's requiring us to use a UDP (called `MultiplyNumbers`) to find the power of the input provided by user (integers). It calls `AddNumbers`, and is using a loop to find the sum.  `CalculatePower` then calls `MultiplyNumbers`, and does so n times (based on input) I've got it working with small numbers, such as 2^3, or 5^2, but when I step it up, such as 10^5, it coughs out a wrong answer. I'm not sure what I'm screwing up here, but any insight would be fantastic.

Here is my code.

```
    INCLUDE Irvine32.inc


    .data
str1 BYTE "Enter a positive integer: ",0
str2 BYTE "The sum is: ",0
str3 BYTE "The product is: ",0
str4 BYTE "The power result is: ",0
num1 DWORD 0
num2 DWORD 0
sum  DWORD 0
prod DWORD 0
pow  DWORD 0
temp  DWORD 0 // used for counting loop in MultiplyNumbers
count DWORD 0 // used for indexing loop in CalculatePower

    .code
main PROC

   call GetInteger;         // Getting input
   mov num1, eax;
   call GetInteger;
   mov num2, eax;



    mov eax, num1;          // Calculations
    mov ebx, num2;
    call AddNumbers;    
    mov edx, OFFSET str2    ;
    mov eax, sum;
    call displayResults

    mov eax,num2;
    mov temp,eax; // indexing loop counter
    xor eax,eax;
    call MultiplyNumbers;
    mov edx, OFFSET str3;
    mov eax, prod;
    call displayResults

    call CalculatePower;
    mov edx, OFFSET str4;
    call WriteString;
    mov eax, pow;
    call displayResults

    invoke ExitProcess, 0

main ENDP

GetInteger PROC
    ;-----------------------------------------------------
    ; Displays the results of previous procedure
    ; Receives:
    ; Returns: nothing
    ;-----------------------------------------------------

    mov edx, OFFSET str1;
    call WriteString;
    call ReadInt;
    ret
GetInteger ENDP

AddNumbers PROC
    ;-----------------------------------------------------
    ; Displays the results of previous procedure
    ; Receives:
    ; Returns: nothing
    ;----------------------------------------------------- 
    add eax, ebx;
    mov sum, eax;
    ret
AddNumbers ENDP

MultiplyNumbers PROC
    ;-----------------------------------------------------
    ; Calculates the multiplication of the intgers provided by the user.
    ; Receives:
    ; Returns: nothing
    ;-----------------------------------------------------
    mov ebx, num1;
    mov ecx, temp; // setting the loop counter;
    MultiLoop:
    call AddNumbers;
    loop MultiLoop;
    mov prod, eax;
    ret
MultiplyNumbers ENDP

CalculatePower PROC    
    ;-----------------------------------------------------
    ; Calculates the power of the intger provided by user
    ; Receives:
    ; Returns: nothing
    ;-----------------------------------------------------          

    mov eax,num2
    mov count,eax; // used to count for powerLoop
    mov eax,num1;
    mov temp,eax; // setting the count for the multiplication loop
    xor eax,eax; // clearing eax

    powerLoop:
    call MultiplyNumbers;
    dec count; // decreasing count for powerLoop
    mov ecx,count; // moving decreased count to index for power loop;
    loop PowerLoop;
    mov pow, eax;
    ret
    CalculatePower ENDP



    displayResults PROC
    ;-----------------------------------------------------
    ; Displays the results of previous procedure
    ; Receives:
    ; Returns: nothing
    ;-----------------------------------------------------

call WriteString        ; display string
call WriteInt           ; display sum
call crlf           ; advance to next line
ret
DisplayResults ENDP


END main
```

Comment: Instead of `X^Y` you seem to be calculating something like `(X^2) * (Y-1)`. For 2^3 and 5^2 that'd work out to the correct result, but not for 10^5.

Answer (score 0):

**Let's analyse your functions**

- `AddNumbers` sums EAX and EBX and stores the result in `sum`
- `MultiplyNumbers` doesn't set EAX on entry, but sets EBX to `num1` and ECSX to `temp`. So it realize the computation: `EAX+num1*temp` and stores the result in `prod` **and** EAX
- `CalculatePower` sets `count` to `num2`, sets `tmp` to `num1` and EAX to 0. It then calls `MultiplyNumbers` `count-1` times (because you decrement `count` before moving to ECX which is decremented by LOOP). So it is computing: `0+num1*num1` on first iteration, `EAX+(num1*num1) = (0+num1*num1)+(num1*num1)` on the second iteration, and so on.

So the whole computation is wrong, what is computed is: `num1^2*(num2-1)`.

It just happens that when `num1=2` and `num2=3` then `2^2*(3-1)==2^3`. But this is pure luck. The computation is wrong.

**Potential solution**

The problem with your code is the reliance on global variables to pass parameters to function. The usual ways of writing assembly functions without side effects are:

1. To rely on parameters passed on the stack and the callee preserve registers values.
2. To use some defined registers to pass parameters and the callers preserves these registers on the stack.

You can also mix the two, for instance always consider some registers will be destroyed by a function call (EAX for instance) and the caller saves it. And consider some other registers must be preserved by the callee.

Comment: Wow. I feel like a total idiot. I think my biggest problem was I was over thinking everything way too much. I tend to do that. Thanks for your help,fjardon, I got it figured out, and your post helped me a lot. I keep forgetting that assembly is pretty simple, and I need to stop making stuff complicated. If you're ever in Atlanta, I'll buy you a beer!

Comment: @srallen87 I'm glad it helped :) Just a little reminder, as I see you're new on the site, to show to others that an answer was useful you can upvote it. And if it solved your problem, you can *accept it as an answer*.